# Convergence of the sequence $x_n = \sqrt{x_{n-1}x_{n-2}}$ for all $n\geq3$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $\left\{x_n\right\}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that $x_n = \sqrt{x_{n-1}x_{n-2}}$ for all $n\geq3$. Then show that the sequence converges to $(x_1x_2^2)^{1/3}$.

How can I do the sum? I have learnt Squeeze theorem, ratio test and root test for convergence of sequence, but I am not sure whether those theorems will help in solving this sum. Please give some hint to approach it.

Please anyone help me solve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write out the powers of the first couple of terms, and use induction to prove the general form of the $n$th term. Not hard to guess

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2803971/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1968340/42969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $(x_{n+1})^2 x_n = x_n x_{n-1} x_n = x_n^2 x_{n-1}$, and so this is constant. So if $x_n$ converges to $a$ (we know it converges by the monotone convergence theorem), we have $a^3 = x_1 x_2^2$, as required.

Comment: @user587389 Note that the definition of $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{x_n x_{n-1}}$ yields that $(x_{n+1})^2 x_n = x_n^2 x_{n-1}$, which is simply reducing $n$ by $1$. We now successively reduce $n$ to obtain $1$.